# Android: how to make a vertical Activity transition with another Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-transitions

I have a ListView in my first Activity. And when I click on an item inside I start another Activity. Ok for that. But now I want to modify the transition between these 2 activities:

1. Activity1 -> Activity2 : vertical transition for Activity2 from bottom to top (progression)
2. When I back to Activity1 : vertical transition for Activity2 from top to bottom (progression)

**UPDATE**

I found a solution according my requirements:

Activity1 -> Activity2

```
startActivity();
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.from_bottom_to_top, 0);
```

from_botton_to_top.xml

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
android:fromYDelta="100%p" android:toYDelta="0%p"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"/>
```

Activity2 -> Activity1 (backpressed key)

```
finish();
overridePendingTransition(0, R.anim.from_top_to_bottom);
```

from_top_to_bottom.xml

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
android:fromYDelta="0%p" android:toYDelta="100%p"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `overridePendingTransition` to change the Activity animation.

For the 1st case you can use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);                     
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.abc_slide_in_bottom, R.anim.abc_slide_out_top);
```

For the 2nd case choose other animations and call `overridePendingTransition`
in `onBackPressed` or after `finish`. `overridePendingTransition` should be called right after your activity finishes.

If you are looking for animations, take a look at the google API samples.
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/res/anim/
There a lot of simple and useful animation xml's.

But `abc_slide_in_bottom` and `abc_slide_in_bottom` are in the google appcompat lib since some years. `abc_slide_out_bottom` and `abc_slide_in_top` also.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help. So for the transition from ActivityA to ActivityB it's ok (overridePendingTransition(R.anim.abc_slide_in_bottom, 0); But from ActivityB to ActivityA it doesn't work properly : overridePendingTransition(0, R.anim.from_top_to_bottom) :
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromYDelta="0" android:toYDelta="-100%p"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `anim`. First create two xml files and put them in `res/anim`

from_bottom_to_top.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="100%p"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        />
</set>
```

from_top_to_bottom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:toYDelta="100%p"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        />
</set>
```

Then, when you start your activity (using startActivity), after that immediately call over overridePendingTransition(int enterAnim, int exitAnim).

You can achieve the same thing when finishing ActivityB (call finish and right after overridePendingTransation).

You can play with the animations and create your one/tweak them.